# Ошибка на сборке игры для андроид на Unity

Tags: android-studio, unity3d

[image]

при сборке игры у меня вылетела вот такая ошибка что мне делать?

CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_192\bin\java.exe -classpath "D:\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.2.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[
C:\Users\??.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\UnityChannel.aar\511a9ccad19470a56a8b430524dc5fcc\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\mio_img_title.png: error: file not found.

C:\Users\??.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\UnityChannel.aar\511a9ccad19470a56a8b430524dc5fcc\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\mio_btn_bg_click.png: error: file not found.

C:\Users\??.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\UnityChannel.aar\511a9ccad19470a56a8b430524dc5fcc\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\mio_mipay_payment_arrow.png: error: file not found.

C:\Users\??.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\UnityChannel.aar\511a9ccad19470a56a8b430524dc5fcc\res\layout\mio_activity_paylist.xml: error: file not found.

C:\Users\??.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\UnityChannel.aar\511a9ccad19470a56a8b430524dc5fcc\res\drawable\mio_selector_mipayment_item.xml: error: file not found.

C:\Users\??.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\UnityChannel.aar\511a9ccad19470a56a8b430524dc5fcc\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\mio_btn_change_account_sel.png: error: file not found.

C:\Users\??.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\UnityChannel.aar\511a9ccad19470a56a8b430524dc5fcc\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\ic_launcher.png: error: file not found.

C:\Users\??.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\UnityChannel.aar\511a9ccad19470a56a8b430524dc5fcc\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\mio_btn_change_account_nor.png: error: file not found.

C:\Users\??.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\UnityChannel.aar\511a9ccad19470a56a8b430524dc5fcc\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\mio_list_item_single_bg_60_n.9.png: error: file not found.

C:\Users\??.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\UnityChannel.aar\511a9ccad19470a56a8b430524dc5fcc\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\mio_list_item_single_bg_60_p.9.png: error: file not found.

C:\Users\??.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\UnityChannel.aar\511a9ccad19470a56a8b430524dc5fcc\res\layout\mio_item_pay.xml: error: file not found.

C:\Users\??.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\UnityChannel.aar\511a9ccad19470a56a8b430524dc5fcc\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\mio_btn_bg.png: error: file not found.

C:\Users\??.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\UnityChannel.aar\511a9ccad19470a56a8b430524dc5fcc\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\mio_pad_bg_float_win.png: error: file not found.

C:\Users\??.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\UnityChannel.aar\511a9ccad19470a56a8b430524dc5fcc\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\mio_mipay_payment_wx.png: error: file not found.

C:\Users\??.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\UnityChannel.aar\511a9ccad19470a56a8b430524dc5fcc\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\mio_icon_login_wait.png: error: file not found.

C:\Users\??.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\UnityChannel.aar\511a9ccad19470a56a8b430524dc5fcc\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\mio_mipay_payment_alipay.png: error: file not found.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':mergeReleaseResources'.

  > Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
]
stdout[
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeReleaseResources
Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
:mergeReleaseResources FAILED
8 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 7 up-to-date
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1 progress, System.String error)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Build completed with a result of 'Failed'
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x0021f] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:187 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (Boolean askForBuildLocation, BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x0007f] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:94 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Assets/Standard Assets/Editor/CrossPlatformInput/CrossPlatformInputInitialize.cs(36,34): warning CS0618: `UnityEditor.BuildTarget.Tizen' is obsolete:`Tizen has been removed in 2017.3'

Comment: Следовать инструкции на сообщении) и смотреть в консоль для дополнительной информации. Можете её и сюда приложить, чтобы было легче вам помочь

Comment: я прикрепил ошибки

Comment: Ошибка смешивания ресурсов. Вы используете какие-либо плагины?

Comment: нет я не использую плагины

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При билде попробуйте изменить  поле Build System c Gradle на Iternal

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое!